# how to reverse automatic trigger 'click' operation in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:
It triggers automatic `click` on button when I select a `checkbox`. However, What should I do to `unclick` or deselect the button. I have tried `unbind()`, but does not seem to work.Any help would be great.

```
if(this.checked) { 
    $("#input").trigger('click');
    }
else  {
    $("#input").unbind('click');
}
```

Comment: Do you mean blur(), like opposite of focus() in your case?

Comment: yes, exactly. so that the button automatically gets unclicked as it gets clicked with trigger.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your code as below:-

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkme"/><input type="submit" name="sendNewSms" class="inputButton" id="sendNewSms" value=" Send " />
```

**JS**

```
var checker = document.getElementById('checkme');
var sendbtn = document.getElementById('sendNewSms');
checker.onchange = function() {
  sendbtn.disabled = !!this.checked;
};
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/n9z5D/)**

Comment: this is just to change color. I need to click and unclick the button

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/n9z5D/2588/)

```
var check = document.getElementById('check');
var btnsend = document.getElementById('send');
check.onchange = function() {
btnsend.click();
  btnsend.disabled = !!this.checked;
};

sendbtn.onclick=function(){
alert("hello");
}
```